# How to hide dlls that I install from users view

Tags: c#, deployment, setup-deployment, installation-package

Hello:
I am developing an application that has a lot of support dll's.  some suppoting dll's, some component dll's.

I install my application into Program Files, but if you were to open up the install location, it looks pretty ugle, just becasue its a long list of dll's.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to not have them to end-users view?
Can I put them in some kind of cab file or some kind of container so users only see a single file?  Can I still use the dll's at runtime if they are packed in a container?

Open to suggestions.

BTW, the program is in C#, using some managed dll's and unmanaged dll's.

thanks
DC

Comment: This is a strange practice, looking at any progrm folders for MS etc. all the dll's are viewable.

Comment: I know...it's quite ok to see dll's but I thought it would be nice to clean it up {if possible}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the managed DLLs you have a couple of options:

- Use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). ILMerge has a nice GUI interface that can be found [here](http://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/)
- Embebed them as a resource, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0) is what you are looking for.

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used
>   to merge multiple .NET assemblies into
>   a single assembly. ILMerge takes a set
>   of input assemblies and merges them
>   into one target assembly.  It works on
>   executables and DLLs alike and comes
>   with several options for controlling
>   the processing and format of the
>   output.

PS: Don't think it merges unmanaged code though.